# Pure CSS 3 image slider with autoplay and overlay text

Tags: html, css, animation

So I'm trying to make a pure CSS3 autoplaying image slider on a web page project I'm doing. So the HTML of the page looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/c0ZiyHGd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Joelson Querub</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a>
      <a href="loja.html">Loja</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div id="pinto">
      <h1>Joelson Querub</h1>
      <div id="images">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517423568366-8b83523034fd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=92b82a18bf4bfbdfe1bd7eed8cd4ba49&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80"
          alt="Pug Fofoso">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=71d59cd22de21da8d2939bc203617983&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1560&q=80"
          alt="Pug Fofoso">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e79d1986f31127432328ba0b78f0b510&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80"
          alt="Pug Fofoso">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529088363398-8efc64a0eb95?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=179403fa836a063432aec8ccc04ee248&auto=format&fit=crop&w=424&q=80"
          alt="Pug Fofoso">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

So what I want is to only one pug image appear at a time, and to make them automatically slide leftwards. The size is important, and the current size is the one I want. Also, notice that there is a text overlaying the image. That text must stay there. I would like to do a smooth slide that is infinite, but that doesn't do that subtle return to the first image.

I tried my luck with some CSS but it din't go very far. You guys can take a look:

https://pastebin.com/S2UZ4uK2

Or for an easier way to see it all:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwWgoX

Though CodePen messes up with the text positioning.

Comment: Please make your commend more specific.  Right now you are saying "please fix my code", as opposed to, "please help me fix this specific problem with my code".

Answer (score 0):

You can use wowslider. [Wowslider](http://wowslider.com/) . Just download the software. You can easily add any picture and also any kind of sliding transformation.